# TypeError: Type is not callable

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

```
 function calculateBNBReward(address ofAddress) public view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 totalSupply = uint256(totalFee)
    .sub(_gonBalances(address(0)))
    .sub(_gonBalances(0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD)) // exclude burned wallet
    .sub(_gonBalances(address(pair)));
    // exclude liquidity wallet

    return Utils.calculateBNBReward(
        totalFee,
        _gonBalances(address(ofAddress)),
        address(this).balance,
        totalSupply,
        ofAddress
    );
}
```

I got this error in this function.
It says Type is not callable

[image]

Full source:https://github.com/laronlineworld/typeError/blob/main/typeError.sol

Comment: Can you include more of the code? It is likely the problems is in another line that surrounds the error.

Comment: This is the full sourcehttps://github.com/laronlineworld/typeError/blob/main/typeError.sol

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `_gonBalances` is a mapping

```
mapping(address => uint256) private _gonBalances;
```

You have to replace `_gonBalances(ADDRESS)` by `_gonBalances[ADDRESS]`.